# ####ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: android

I tried to compile the Android source code according to the official documentation, but encountered a problem, the error log is as follows. who can help me

```
    [100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
Killed
07:00:40 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

##### failed to build some targets (03:06:10 (hh:mm:ss))

[errors description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inSWx.png)

Comment: Reminder to avoid posting images when text is possible. Did you read the message at the top of your linked image: `You are building on a machine with 3.83GB of RAM. The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB`.

Comment: First, I use make -j8 , but it gives an error, then I try to use make -j4 aapt , but it fails

Comment: I have set the ubuntu system corresponding to the vm virtualbox, settings-system-processor-number of processors to 8

Answer (score 0):

You were building on a very low ram machine, so most likely your building process was killed because of `OOM` occured. You can run `dmesg` to see if you got any `Out of memory:  kill process <your compile pid>` log to check if that is the reason or not.

If `OOM` is the cause, I think the only way is to increase the `swap` size and change `make -j4` to `make -j1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it failed again, I tried to download the source code and compile again

Comment: `jiangwei@jiangwei-VirtualBox:~/aosp$ make -j1
21:28:34 ************************************************************
21:28:34 You are building on a machine with 3.83GB of RAM
21:28:34 
21:28:34 The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
21:28:34 and even with that, some configurations may not work.
21:28:34 
21:28:34 If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
21:28:34 -j value.
21:28:34 ************************************************************
============================================
`

Comment: `PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=11
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.13.0-40-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-20.04.4-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
`

Comment: `[100% 180/180] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
Killed
23:54:36 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

#### failed to build some targets (02:26:22 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
`

Comment: Try to set more ram size for the virtual machine, and set more swap size, Or switch to a machine with a bigger ram size. I think there have no other options to solve the OOM problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase memory swap. That will fix it. That is what I did.